She thrust past him angrily and left. (physically pushed him or just walked forward in front of him?)

She thrust past him angrily and left.

I found this sentence in my dictionary, studying 'thrust' and wondered if she physically pushed him or just walked forward in front of him.
'thrust past somebody' is a phrase like an idiom? What's the exact meaning of the phrase?

A thrust is a sudden, rapid movement in a straight-ahead direction. Consider swordmanship, which involves a variety of blade-motions, one of which is the straight-ahead push with the blade. The word can be used literally:

The blacksmith thrust the hot metal into a vat of oil to quench the steel.

or  figuratively of any motion,  structure, or land feature that follows a more-or-less straight-ahead, unvarying path:

The shoppers thrust their way to the holiday sale rack.
The sea thrusts inland at that point along the coast.
The smokestacks of the coal district thrust skyward.


Collins Dictionary sense 2 says

If you thrust your way somewhere, you move there, pushing between people or things which are in your way.

thrust

She thrust past him angrily and left.

The sentence doesn't state clearly whether she physically pushed him, but the phrase past him suggests close proximity.  Hence
that likelihood is there, and she at least jostled him.
For example, he could be at the doorway trying to stop her  from leaving.
In a different situation, if they were in a crowd and he was just a few metres away (so that past him still applies) from her path going out, then she wouldn't have pushed him.  This is less likely.

It implies that she at least jostled him (knocked him with her elbow in passing).

Thanks,  @Kate Bunting.  I've incorporated that.

i think meaning like this sentence:

He, in his car, thrust past the other car very quickly and rapidly

that means car very fast and its fast,thrust pasted(pushed->air and air pushed-> other car) other car.
